# AngularJS template and AngularJS view differences

Tags: angularjs

What is the exact difference between Template and View in AngularJS.
Both terms are defined separately in the guide [can be found here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts). Both seems to the same to me but question is lot of times people uses both terms for different purposes which i never understood till now.

I found some links on stackoverflow as well but its not answered correctly.

Could anyone please help me here to find out the differences ? (if any)

Comment: "Template" is just the HTML with special Angular expressions (e.g. `{{foo}}` or `ng-repeat="item in items"` that assume some value or perform some action. "View" is a concept in MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) to denote the presentation layer of the app. Templates typically belong in the View

Comment: @New Dev: Technically "View" is also nothing but HTML (with/without Angular expressions) isn't it?

Comment: Moreover templates are static so they can be cached and the template can be filled with data at client end.

Comment: @Parashuram In the general case, the split between a 'View' and a 'Template' is so that if you are going to present the view data via different methods [ie. HTML, XML, JSON, etc.] then you do not need to keep rewriting the 'View', only create new 'Templates'.

Comment: @brute_force: if templates are static then how can i fill with data?

Comment: @brute_force: Your second comment makes some sense.

Comment: @Parashuram, "View" is a concept (it is implemented with HTML in Angular, but could be XAML in .NET). Sure, in a special case, the View could contain HTML without Angular expressions.. but then, it is not an MVVM application

Comment: @NewDev: Sorry but i couldn't get it. You mean to say, if the HTML contains no angular expressions,it wont fall under the term "View" in angular ?

Comment: If HTML contains no Angular expressions, then in what sense is it an "Angular app"? The whole point of Angular (and MVVM) is that the View is automatically updated via bindings to the ViewModel. At any rate, this question asks for theoretical definitions and terminology, and not a good fit for SO